# "privileged" method calling member method issue

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Consider the following code:

```
function Dog()
{
    this.foo = function() {};

    this.walk = function()
    {
        if(canWalk())
        {
            alert('walking');
            return;
        }

        alert('I have no legs!');
    }

    canWalk = function()
    {
        this.foo();
        return false;
    }
}

var instance = new Dog();
instance.walk();
```

There is a bug in that code with the "privileged" `canWalk()` method assuming the `this` pointer points to the instance of `Dog`.  It actually appears to be pointing to the global object which is confusing me!  I've read that due to closures I can grab a reference to `this` in the scope of the constructor then use that reference in my "privileged" method but that seems like a hack.

I just barely grasp the behavior of the `this` pointer in various contexts.  I understand that a method that is "attached" to an object will receive a `this` pointing to the attached object.  For example, `foo.doStuff()` would have a `this` pointing to the `foo` instance.

What's troubling is that while I think I'm being clever and creating "privileged" methods on my OBJECT, it appears that I'm ACTUALLY dumping functions into global scope! Perhaps there was a global method called `init()` (quite possible) from another library or file not my own creation. If I then defined a nice little encapsulated object with a "privileged" method called `init()` I would be replacing the other global `init()` method.

My question is, what is the best practice for creating "privileged" methods (and fields for that matter) that are scoped to the object they are intended to belong to?  What other approach to my sample object would provide private or privileged methods while also being properly scoped.  I'm not looking for obscure solutions that meet the requirements but rather what the best practice is.

Comment: I can't figure out how to edit my original post, but I realized I made an unfortunate error and didn't paste the correct example code.
There WAS a call to a "foo" method from the canWalk() method, so basically canWalk() was calling this.foo().
Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case `this` was probably pointing to the `canWalk` function. From my example, if you used `self.foo` you'd be fine. And there's probably an edit button somewhere :)

Comment: @Steve you can edit your own post by clicking "edit" just below the blue tags at the bottom left of the text. I tried updating the code with what you described but it was a little unclear.

Comment: I think this is what he's talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/3aMwb/  I believe that showcases the problem.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for trying, I appreciate it.  I click on edit and it pops up a comparison of two versions - I can't actually edit the text.  I have tried logging out and back in, same result.

Comment: @Steve Oxley - JSFiddle is cool, I haven't seen that before, thanks!  You're correct, storing the reference to 'this' in a separate variable solves the problem.  I'm still reviewing some of the other replies, maybe some other options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `this`. Put `var self = this;` at the top of your Dog function and use `self`. That way you will always have a 'safe' reference to the Dog.

In your example `this` should point to the `Dog` though unless I'm missing something as well.

As for your privileged method, you forgot to define the variable. Add `var canWalk;`

There is another way: closures. I will give an example:

```
function create_dog() {
    function canWalk() {
        return false;
    }
    function walk() {
        if (canWalk()) {
            alert("walking");
            return;
        }
        alert("I have no hands!");
    }
    return {
        "walk": walk // points to the function walk()
    }; // this the API of dog, like public functions (or properties)
}
var dog = create_dog();
dog.walk();
```

Now you don't need `this` or `new`. Additionally you could do this:

```
function create_dog() {
    function canWalk() {
        return false;
    }
    function walk() {
        if (canWalk()) {
            alert("walking");
            return;
        }
        alert("I have no hands!");
    }
    var dog = {
        "walk": walk
    };
    return dog;
}
var dog = create_dog();
dog.walk();
```

So you can have references to the `dog` in your priveledges functions. **I would advise the closure approach if you're not going to be using prototyping.**

By the way. To avoid confusion:

```
function my_func() {}
```

and

```
var my_func = function () {};
```

Are equivalent. The latter can be useful if you have a circular reference between two functions and you want to enforce define-before-use.

Comment: +1 Great answer showing how to do the same thing in two totally different ways.

Comment: Why would you switch away from `new Dog` and just create an object?

Comment: If you're not using prototyping there is no advantage to using `new`. A full closure approach is usable, just don't try doing any inheritance.

Comment: Great example!  I would agree this is a good way to go, however your comment towards the end ("... if you're not going to be using prototyping...") and indeed I plan to use prototyping.  You can imagine that Dog will have an "Animal" that it inherits from.

Comment: If you really need the inheritance and polymorphism then you shouldn't use this closure approach, go for a prototype approach. I'm not a big fan of it but it has it's uses. Just be careful when using `this` ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a `var` in front of your `canWalk`. That way, the `canWalk` function is confined to the scope of `dog()`, rather than being an implicit global.

`this` points to the "owner" of the function. When using the `new` operator, the function creates its own scope. So, within the body of `dog()`, `this` refers to the dog instance object. Inside your `walk` function, `this` also refers to the dog instance, because you're setting the `walk` function to an instance of `dog` (`this.walk = function () { ... }`). However, in `canWalk`, there is no owner, so `this` points to the global object, `window`.

I realize that my explanation might be confusing, so here's the code annotation version of my explanation:

```
var obj = {
    'f': function () {
        // this === obj, because obj "owns" this function
        // In other words, this function is callable by obj.f()
    },
    'o': {
         'f': function () {
             // this === obj.o, because obj.o "owns" this function
             // In other words, this function is callable by obj.o.f()
         }
    }
};

// The new operator essentially sets "this" within the 
// function to an empty object and returns that object
var instance = new Dog();

function Dog() {
    // this === instance, because of the "new" operator

    // For demonstration
    var self = this;

    this.walk = function () {
        // this === instance === self, because self/instance "owns" this function
        // In other words, this function is callable by self.walk()
    };

    var canWalk = function () {
        // What's the owner of this object? Nothing,
        // so it defaults to the global object, window
        // this === window

        // Instead, we can access the Dog instance by
        // using the "self" variable we set earlier.
        // self === instance
    };
}
```

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: This is a good explanation of both elements of the situation.  I was only covering the implicit global scope of `canWalk`, so I deleted my answer.  +1

Comment: another good explanation and presentation of things.  I'm a bit embarrassed that I missed the fact that I hadn't used 'var' in front.

Answer (score 1):

As you've gathered, calling canWalk straight up like that means that the 'this' keyword is set to the global object for that function call.

If you want to run the call under the context of the current dog you can explicitly do so like this:

`canWalk.call(this)`

Comment: I found the call() solution as well but decided against using it because it didn't feel correct, it had a smell to it that made me think I should look for a design change instead.  It is good to remember the call() option though.